# C query string parsing

Tags: c, string, parsing, query-string

I have the following query string

```
address=1234&port=1234&username=1234&password=1234&gamename=1234&square=1234&LOGIN=LOGIN
```

I am trying to parse it into different variables: address,port,username,password,gamename,square and command (which would hold LOGIN)

I was thinking of using strtok but I don't think it would work. How can I parse the string to capture the variables ?

P.S - some of the fields might be empty - no gamename provided or square

Comment: By using `strtok`

Comment: Use `strtok` to split by `&` and then use `strchr` to find `=` within token. Are you really *J Doe*?

Comment: If there is a potential for empty-fields (e.g. `"&&"`), then `strtok` cannot be used (it treats consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter). You can however use `strsep`, `strcspn` or `strpbrk` to handle empty field by locating the delimiter. Here you could nest `strtok` within `strsep` calls to use `"&\n"` as the delimiter for `strsep` and then a call to `strtok` using `"=\n"` as the delimiter to separate the `var=value` parts.

Answer (score 4):

When parsing a sting that may contain an empty-field between delimiters, `strtok` cannot be used, because `strtok` will treat any number of sequential delimiters as a single delimiter.

So in your case, if the *variable=values* fields may also contain an empty-field between the `'&'` delimiters, you must use `strsep`, or other functions such as `strcspn`, `strpbrk` or simply `strchr` and a couple of pointers to work your way down the string.

The `strsep` function is a BSD function and may not be included with your C library. GNU includes `strsep` and it was envisioned as a replacement for `strtok` simply because `strtok` cannot handle empty-fields.

(If you do not have `strsep` available, you will simply need to keep a *start* and *end* pointer and use a function like `strchr` to locate each occurrence of `'&'` setting the *end* pointer to one before the delimiter and then obtaining the *var=value* information from the characters between *start* and *end* pointer, then updating both to point one past the delimiter and repeating.)

Here, you can use `strsep` with a delimiter of `"&\n"` to locate each `'&'` (the `'\n'` char included presuming the line was read from a file with a *line-oriented* input function such as `fgets` or POSIX `getline`). You can then simply call `strtok` to parse the *var=value* text from each token returned by `strsep` using `"="` as the delimiter (the `'\n'` having already been removed from the last token when parsing with `strsep`)

An example inserting a specific empty-field for handling between `"...gamename=1234&&square=1234..."`, could be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char array[] =  "address=1234&port=1234&username=1234&password=1234"
                    "&gamename=1234&&square=1234&LOGIN=LOGIN",
        *query = strdup (array),  /* duplicate array, &array is not char** */
        *tokens = query,
        *p = query;

    while ((p = strsep (&tokens, "&\n"))) {
        char *var = strtok (p, "="),
             *val = NULL;
        if (var && (val = strtok (NULL, "=")))
            printf ("%-8s    %s\n", var, val);
        else
            fputs ("<empty field>\n", stderr);
    }

    free (query);
}
```

(**note:** `strsep` takes a `char**` parameter as its first argument and will modify the argument to point one past the delimiter, so you must preserve a reference to the start of the original allocated string (`query` above)).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strsep_query
address     1234
port        1234
username    1234
password    1234
gamename    1234
<empty field>
square      1234
LOGIN       LOGIN
```

(**note:** the conversion of `"1234"` to a numeric value has been left to you)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: hmm why are you `strdup`ing the array separately? Perhaps you mean `char *query = strdup(getenv("QUERY_STRING"))` or similar

Comment: Ooof.. Good question. I'll have to try and recall my thought process. I believe the intent was the take the query string from the question and duplicate it in a form usable by `strsep` -- I wasn't sure the question involved the current user's information (at least that is the best I can recall)

Comment: Also, I don't think there will commonly be empty name-value pairs, but names without `foo=1&bar&baz=2` can be possible, and so can `foo=42&bar=&baz=2`; and same name occurring several times.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I do recall the `"PS - some of the fields might be empty..."` in the question being the reason for `strsep` -- where if by that the OP meant `"...&gamename=&square..."` rather than `"...&&..."`, then `strtok` would be fine. Good catch on the ambiguity, the alternative interpretation never crossed my mind. (until now)

Comment: How would you approach the problem if your query string can also contain escaped characters to be treated as literals, including **\&** and **\=**? And what about quoted strings, e.g., password=1234&gamename="me&you"&etc, so that **me&you** is the value for attribute **gamename**?

Comment: When parsing becomes the most challenging is when there is a lack of consistent delimiters to separate the string by, and the separation must be made on conditions within the string itself. In those cases, you simply use a pair of pointers (or 3 if needed). A start-pointer that you scan down the string until you find the start of your field, an end-pointer, that you scan from your start pointer to the end of your field. You now have your field bracketed between start and end pointers. Now you can simply `memcpy()` the data between them.