# How to use strtok() to extract parts from QUERY_STRING in c?

Tags: html, c, query-string, strtok

Right now I'm working with receiving input from a website we created for our assignment. There is an input field, hidden field, and submit button, which upon clicking returns the following QUERY_STRING to my script.

```
https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~ctonne2/cgi-bin/answer.cgi?inputAns=answer&gold=5
```

I'm currently trying to extract the "answer" and "5" into separate variables, but have run into issue using sscanf, as when I do

```
sscanf(data, "inputAns=%s&gold=%d", input, goldpieces);
```

The  "input" variable becomes the entire end of the string. Therefore, I'm trying to find alternate ways to extract those two variable. The larger script that the submit calls is below, but any help finding a way to parse the QUERY_String would be much appreciated.

answer.c (source script)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char north[]="NORTH",  south[]="SOUTH", east[]="EAST", west[]="WEST", goldSTR[]="GOLD", correct[]="128", separate[]="&";

int  main() {
        char input[100];
        int goldpieces = -100;
        char *data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");

        printf("Content-Type:text/html\n\n");
        printf("<html>");

        if (strstr(data, separate) == NULL) {
                sscanf(data, "inputAns=%s", input);
                printf("%s", input);
        } else {
                scanf(data, "inputAns=%s&gold=%d", input, goldpieces);

        }

        if (goldpieces == -100) goldpieces = 10;

        if (goldpieces<=0) {
                printf("<body> You Lose! Better Luck Next Time </body>");
                return(0);
                }
        if (100<=goldpieces) {
                printf("<body> You Win! Good Job! </body>");
                return(0);
                }

        if (strcmp(input, north)==0) {
                printf("<a href=\"https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~nhawar/cgi-bin/addgold.cgi?gold=%d\" >Press HERE to go North</a>", goldpieces);
        } else if (strcmp(input, south)==0) {
                printf("<a href=\"https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~rsowa/cgi-bin/addgold.cgi?gold=%d\" >Press HERE to go South</a>", goldpieces);
        } else if (strcmp(input, east)==0)  {
                printf("<a href=\"https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~bemili/cgi-bin/addgold.cgi?gold=%d\" >Press HERE to go East</a>", goldpieces);
        } else if (strcmp(input, west)==0)  {
                printf("<a href=\"https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~akragl/cgi-bin/addgold.cgi?gold=%d\" >Press HERE to go West</a>", goldpieces);
        } else if (strcmp(input, goldSTR)==0) {
                printf ("<body> Your gold total is: </body>");
                printf("%d", goldpieces);
                printf("<br></br>");
                printf("<a href=\"https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~ctonne2/cgi-bin/addgold.cgi?gold=%d\" >Press HERE to go back</a>", goldpieces);
        } else if (strcmp(input, correct) == 0) {
                goldpieces+=10;
                printf("<body> You are correct! Accept 10 gold as a reward </body>");
                printf("<a href=\"https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~ctonne2/cgi-bin/addgold.cgi?gold=%d\" >Press HERE to go back</a>",goldpieces);
        } else {
                goldpieces-=5;
                printf("<body> That was not the correct answer. Womp Womp. </body>");
                printf("<a href=\"https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~ctonne2/cgi-bin/addgold.cgi?gold=%d\">Press HERE to go back</a>", goldpieces);
                }

        printf("</html>");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is an answer already on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575521/c-query-string-parsing.

Comment: Note that `/answer.cgi?gold=5&inputAns=answer` would be a valid URI, so parsing should consume everything after the `?`, split by the `&` token, then parse into key/value pairs by `=`.

Comment: I would recommend using a loop to solve the problem using the functions `strtok` and `strchr` to target tokens `/?&` from calling `strtok` which contain `=` from calling `strchr`.